# Flex module error

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flex4

I'm trying to load a module into a flex 4 application (the module was compiled using SDK4 as well) but I got this error (I'm migrating this app from Flex 3 to Flex 4):

VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.core::LayoutContainer could not be found.

```
at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory/deferredNextFrame()
at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory/update()
at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory/moduleCompleteHandler()
```

ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Step3_img_logo is not defined.

```
at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory/deferredNextFrame()
at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory/update()
at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory/moduleCompleteHandler()
```

I'm using this code to add the module to a VBox:

var module:ModuleLoader =  new ModuleLoader();
module.url = "layout/ImportContacts.swf?id_user=45";
moduleContainer.addChild(module);

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was I created the module in a different project and it was optimized for it. tks.

Comment: Hi, how did you solve this issue?  I cannot fix it.  When I run my app on a mobile device, it gives me this exactly same error.

Answer (score 0):

is your module compiled as Spark or Halo instance?

Did you load all RSLs you need?